# Magento multistore, __store and ___from_store in URL

Tags: multistore, url, multidomain

we are setting up a multistore. Now we see "__store and ___from_store" in the UR. Is there an easy (and accepted method) of utilizing the functionality, but hiding the url string "__store and ___from_store"

So moving from domain1.com => domain2.com does not result in

> http://domain2.com/?___store=domain1&___from_store=domain1

but rather

> http://domain2.com/

thanks!

Comment: See System > Config > Web > Add Store Code

Comment: Setting is set to NO. Are you suggesting to switch this to YES?

Comment: @snh_nl I am asking some info apart from your post, i am created multi-store, using http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-setup-multiple-website/. I am using the same theme for both stores, how can i change header and footer for my second store, pls keep in mind same theme. What is the use of symlinks?

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution is to change the your `page/switch/languages.phtml` file

Find the line that reads

`echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl()`

And replace with

`echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl(false)`

**Option 2**

Go to **System -> Configuration -> Web -> URL Options** and set the 'Add Shop Code to URLs' option to **Yes**

This will make the urls to the store appear like the following:

www.myshop.com/otherstore/

www.myshop.com/default/

To edit the names of your stores to be SEO friendly, go to **System -> Manage Shops**

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @mbalparda and [this article](http://www.mcnab.co/blog/e-commerce/magento/magento-urls-remove-the-appended-store-parameter/)

Actually setting the option "System > Config > Web > Add Store Code" to YES:
removes __store from the url because Magento now uses /storecode/ to identify which store needs to be opened.

Open question: is how does this work with storeviews that are on different domains? Here I don't think you would want this setting set to YES ...

Answer (score 3):

Magento Enterprise does this with a redirect as soon as the `__store` parameter is recognized and the store cookie has been set. With an observer on `controller_front_init_before` you should be able to rebuild this feature for CE.

Comment: Do you mean `controller_front_init_before`?

Comment: @Simon: yes. I shouldn't try to write event names without looking them up :)